# How Non Clustered Index Works

Tags: sql, indexing

I studied difference between Clustered and Non Clustered indexes. I found that Non Clustered indexes are stored in logical form. 
Can some one please explain me how this logical form works exactly ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The clustered indexes insert data in sorted order and leaf nodes contains the actual data.

Although non-clustered index structure is same but the leaf node contains a value and a pointer to the actual row.
The non-clustered indexes doesn't change the physical order of the rows. And that makes it "store in logical form".
I found the Dusan Petkovic's artical very useful to understand index structure.
[Non-Clustered Indexe Indices](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/sql-server-nonclustered-indices-mc03/#.V7q-Kvl97IU)